# Java main method not recognized in jar file, but compiles fine

Tags: java, jar, package, program-entry-point, javac

The first thing I'd like to point out is that I don't use IDEs. I use Notepad++ which has minimal assistance and I compile and run all my code from bash or DOS. In this case, I'm attempting to run a file in Java as an executable jar file using the command `java -jar CharDefs.jar` but it always gives me the message: `Main method not found in LispDefs.CharDefs, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args).`

So far, I have gone through the tutorials on Oracle's site and created a manifest file by making a text file called `Manifest.txt` with the line `Main-Class: LispDefs.CharDefs` and a carriage return.
I included this into my jar file with the command `jar cfm LispDefs.jar Manifest.txt LispDefs/*.class` as indicated on their tutorial.
The file created successfully, but it still gives me the message. However, when I compile the file without the package header and run it with java.exe alone, then it runs successfully. Here is my code:

```
//package LispDefs;

public class CharDefs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(lChar("hello"));
        System.out.println(rChar("hello"));
    }

    public static String cChar(String var1, String var2) {
        return var1.concat(var2);
    }

    public static String lChar(String var1) {
        if (var1.length() == 0) {
            return new String();
        }

        if (var1.length() == 1) {
            return String.valueOf(var1.charAt(0));
        }

        return String.valueOf(var1.charAt(0));
    }

    public static String rChar(String var1) {
        if (var1.length() == 0) {
            return new String();
        }

        if (var1.length() == 1) {
            return new String();
        }

        String temp = new String();
        for (int k = 1; k < var1.length(); k++) {
            temp = temp.concat(String.valueOf(var1.charAt(k)));
        }

        return temp;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create a package of different classes that allow different layers of LISP style list parsing methods that can be applied generically across different programs. Right now, I'm just trying to test running it by itself, but it's not recognizing my main method in the jar executable. I read other articles and tried various things and it seems like maybe there's some sort of semantic error or something I didn't notice perhaps. I'm not too used to Java, as I'm sort of porting this concept over from python.

Comment: You tell how you try and run the generated jar, not how you actually try and compile the stuff; show the full process

Comment: Strange code. You could simplify these methods enormously. You need to post your Manifest file and a listing of the JAR file.

Comment: To be specific, the second `if` in `lChar()` and both `if`s in `rChar()` can be removed.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I no longer have access to this code, but there wasn't really much more to it at the time than this. So, I may revitalize this project at some point and use this post as a basis for the code used.

I realize it is a bit strange. I wrote it during an odd time of stubbornness when I had a specific way of doing things that basically attempted to imitate languages like assembly and LISP directly and threw coding conventions aside as they're used in modern languages. So, the multiple if statements were imitating the way AND/OR is done in digital electronics and I hated try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

Probable your `Manifest.txt` file does not end with a new line.

Another way to solve your problem is created JAR with manifest using that command:

```
jar cfe jar-file main-class input-file(s)
```

Then `Manifest` file will be created automatically. So, in your case, this command can look like this:

```
jar cfe LipsDefs.jar CharDefs *
```

or if you have package:

```
jar cfe LipsDefs.jar LispDefs.CharDefs LispDefs/*
```

More information you can find here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: Not quite. He needs `LispDefs/*.class`, not `*`.

Comment: The package is commented out.

Comment: Read the question. The package being commented in/out is discussed therein.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you misread, or glossed over some details of, how an "executable jar" is made.

First of all, you have a source directory in which you have your source files (files whose names end up with `.java`, with an appropriate directory structure; I understand that you know that much).

What you need to do is compile those files in your source directory(ies) into a destination directory (THIS MAY BE THE SAME); and in addition, in one of your source directories, you should have a file named (relatively):

`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

And in that file, have a line which reads:

`Main-Class: relative.path.to.MyMainClass`

where:

`relative/path/to/MyMainClass.java`

has a `main` method with the prototype:

`public static void main(String... args) // or String[] args`

So, the basic process is:

- know what your source directory is, where your `.java` files are;
- know what your destination directory is;
- issue the compile process appropriately; manually copy files not handled by the compile process (**this includes `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`**) in the destination directory;
- make a jar out of the destination directory.

All in all, the contents of your build directory should be:

- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (with the Main-Class in it, at least);
- **/*.class (your compiled Java files).

And you should be able to make an "executable jar" out of it.

Of course, if you have external dependencies, the problem is more complicated than that...